# laravel master layout override debugging page

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am used to when the error occurs in my application, the orange screen with debugging information shows. I created a basic master layout template to use for my site, and suddenly the orange error page doesn't show any more. This is really weird. Any suggestions as to how to solve this?

This is a picture of how it looks now..[image]

Log file content shared for support:

```
Next exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Route [signup] not defined. (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/app/views/general/index.blade.php)' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php:5512
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(9499): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(InvalidArgumentException))
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(56): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Applications/M...', Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(9375): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/Applications/M...', Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(9362): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(9353): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(10048): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(9583): Illuminate\Http\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(4832): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(4658): Illuminate\Routing\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(4644): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(698): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(679): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(1136): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(7219): Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(7816): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(7763): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(10771): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#17 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/bootstrap/compiled.php(640): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#19 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopcon/index.php(19): require_once('/Applications/M...')
#20 {main} [] []
```

Comment: did you made any updates to PHP / or changed how php interacts with apache ? or installed some caching system ?

Comment: nope nothing at all. New installation created a basic style sheet and created master layout. Extended it in my view and that's all I got.

Comment: can you attach your laravel.log file ? or at least the last part of it ?

Comment: app/storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: also make sure that your 'debug'=>true in your config/app.php

Comment: Like `seblaze` said that, `make sure that your 'debug'=>true in your config/app.php`.

Comment: I understand from the above quoted error log that the routes were not included (my bad) but that doesn't answer my question as to why am not getting this in the orange page where errors are usually displayed.

Comment: someone can post this as answer and I will select it as so. Thanks guys @seblaze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make the '`debug'=>true` in your `app/config/app.php` file

```
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => true,
```

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that `debug` is set to `true` in your `app/config/app.php` file like this:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
*/

'debug'=>true,
```

If `'debug'=>true` is set then you'll see that orange screen for errors.